react reloading when I manually change data of a varaiable in its file
example is data.js export const x={value:0};
in app.js :
import { x } from "./data";
function App() {
  return (
  
    <div>
      {console.log("Re-render")}
      {x.value}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;


when i manually change the x.value in data.js react is reloading/re-rendering. why ?
i thought then value of x.value would stay 0 even if i changes its value manually to 100;

It actually doesn't come from React, but from your bundler (Vite or webpack), where there is a HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
When you modifying a chunk of code that affects the UI it will reload all the affected UI with the new code. So when you change value manually, it will change the UI.
You can customize which file you want to trigger HMR but it's generally not a good idea.
Here is the webpack doc : HMR Webpack
And the vite doc : HMR Vite
